# Explanation Bash Command ${PATH}:

Tags: terminal, bash

To make shortcut for command line function to make it available everywhere in my mac i usually add this line in `~/.bash_profile`

To include one terminal execution file, i usually use: `alias yiic='~/Script/Yii/1.1.13/yiic'`
`yiic` is terminal execution file.

And then now i have example this from another site: `export PATH=${PATH}:/development/sdk/android-sdk-macosx/tools`

I understand this command like import all execution file in `tools` directory, but what is the meaning of `${PATH}:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${PATH}` is the other folders that your computer will look in.  It's automatically set up by your OS.  If you do the following command in your Terminal, you'll see all the folders your computer looks in:

```
echo $PATH
```